# Own syntax highlighter

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting

I am about writing own simple syntax highlighter in PHP. I've done basic algorithm based on regular expressions and string replacement, but what I really don't know is way how to disable replacing keywords which are commented.

For example:

```
/**
 * Some class
 *
 * @property-read $foo
 */
 class Test
 {
     private $foo;

     public function __construct()
     {
     }
 }
```

Now my solution simply highlight defined keywords (like class or variables) but also those which are commented.

Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Why not use PHP's [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) to do the job for you? That way, your syntax highlighter will parse the PHP code the exact same way the Zend Engine does, which is probably going to give you a lot better results than a regular expression.

Comment: And faster than regular expressions :)

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking about that but what if I'd like to add multiple-languages support (e.g. html, js etc.)? How should I work with keywords or so in these situations?

Answer (score 1):

Why not borrow lessons from how vi or vim already does this? long back I remember for some custom tag based language we developed, we wanted syntax highlighting in VI and VIM , that is when we changed few .vi sort of configuration files where we mentioned, all the meta data like which color to what kind of tag, what are tags possible etc.

Looking more into how vi or vim or any text editor does this might be more helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude the commented lines by this logic:

if line starts with `/**` disable highlight
if next line starts with `*` do nothing and check next line
if line starts with `*/` reenable highlight

Just a quick guess and can be defined more precise, but should work as a logic.

Comment: and also sections starting with `//` and `#` I would assume

Comment: Yeah, would define an array for 'comment starters'

Comment: @Will Vousden: I know there are many possible ways this simple logic can/will fail. It was just a quick guess, not a complete logic to implement